# How do I return lengths of string in an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I have an array of strings and want to output those that are of a certain length from the array.

```
string[]myArray = {"stringone", "stringtwo", "stringthree"};
```

I have tried doing

```
foreach(thing in myArray){
if(thing.length<10){
do stuff
}

@output
```

But doesnt work. Where am i going wrong?
I'm using C# in asp.net.

Many thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error or no output, etc.?

Comment: (var?) `foreach(var thing in myArray)` ? Capitalize `Length`, What error?

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify that `thing` is a `string` or [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Also, you need to capitalize Length.

```
    public void McTester()
    {
        string[] myArray = { "stringone", "stringtwo", "stringthree" };
        foreach (string thing in myArray)
        {
            if (thing.Length < 10)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it may be the capitalisation. I have that variable included i just missed it out above. Will try that out thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] myArray = { "stringone", "stringtwo", "stringthree" };
var lessThan10Length  = myArray.Where(x=> x.Length < 10).ToList();
```

Comment: This will get you the list of all the string with Length < 10... But you would still have to iterate over that list and do stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem was `length` instead of `Length`, you can filter out only the values you need using a `Where` clause:

```
string[] myArray = { "stringone", "stringtwo", "stringthree" };

foreach (string thing in myArray.Where(thing => thing.Length < 10))
{
    // Here you'll only iterate values
    // whos length is less than 10
}
```